# (Mis)usage of private constructor and static methods (Java)?

Tags: java, constructor, static, refactoring, private

I am currently working on a project that needs to be refactored (it was not written by me and the original developer is not around). I see in that application that rather many classes have only private constructors and one or more static methods (getter/setter of the current class object). They also have non-static methods. I give you one example:

Class UndoManager that manages the actions taken on the application for performing undo/redo. It has only private constructors. When the application is loaded, UndoManager.setManager() is called. This method loads the undo history from a file or constructs a new one using a private constructor.

Later, every class can access this instance of UndoManager with syngronized static method .getManager().

In code:

```
public class UndoManager extends SimpleObservable<UndoManager> {

    private static UndoManager instance;
    private final Stack<Action> undoHistory;
    private final Stack<Action> redoHistory;    

    public synchronized static void setManager(UndoManager undoManager) {
        UndoManager instance = getManager();
        instance.clear();
        instance.undoHistory.addAll(undoManager.undoHistory);
        instance.redoHistory.addAll(undoManager.redoHistory);
        instance.notifyObservers(instance);
    }

    public synchronized static UndoManager getManager() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new UndoManager();
        return instance;
    }

    private UndoManager() {
        this.undoHistory = new Stack<Action>();
        this.redoHistory = new Stack<Action>();
    }
    /.../
}
```

In this application multiple classes are used like this. They are not helper classes but classes that should have only one instance.

My question is:
is this kind of access good style? If not, how would you refactor the class and it's access?

I'm sorry if it is a duplicate, but I have searched in stackoverflow and google for a while but somehow I didn't find a satisfying answer. Thank you for any help.

Comment: It is called the Singleton Design Pattern. It has its moments, but typically its just the lazy way out.

Comment: so as the instance is static there can only be one.  I don't understand then why pass in the undoManager to setManager and then go and get the same instance.  Looks like it was refactored (not fully) as some stage.  But rule No. 1 is if it ain't broke don't try and fix it.  Is it broken?

Comment: @Karthik T you mention it is often a lazy way out - can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @RebaneLumes Atleast in a previous place that I worked at, instead of a heirarchy of objects based on ownership, we had 1 singleton for each class, just to make it easier to access. The next project we fixed this, but it led to a lot of `getXXX().getYYY().getZZZ().setA(b)`

Comment: But that gave us cleaner code over all and more freedom to do things which would not have worked with the singleton pattern. Moral : You might need to use occasionally but beware of overusing it. (other more brilliant minds have talked much more on this subject, simple googling of "singleton bad" might give you enough)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
It is part of the great familly of designs patterns you might know them.

The point of this is to ensure that there is only one instance of this object used throughout your application. Indeed when you call `getManager()` it will return a new instance the first time and next times it will return the formerly created instance.

Answer (score 1):

it's a design pattern that called [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). it's a lazy load and used for managers classes and service classes for example. they are for classes that you want an instance but only one instance of them.

there is usually a method to get the instance like your `getManager` method and a private constructor like you have